# Anylogic : modeling parking lot

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to model the parking lot using road traffic library. However, the example mostly gas station is only give me an idea on queue problems not a parking lot.

Can anyone guide me on the idea of how I can set the parking lot problem in any logic tools?? i.e. vehicles are coming in the parking lot and randomly select the space and holding in the space in some period before exit.

I am really confusing on how to set the parking lot spaces in the model.

Thank you in advances

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find an object that directly does that. 
I'll probably start by looking at defining the lot with nodes and paths and model the lots as a resource. when a car comes in it requests a resource from the lot-pool.

To release it again you have different options. The easy way is just a random delay before it is released, if you want to specify a specific car to release you'll need to have a function to pick those out.